# How do I override compare_fields when using Rose::HTML::Form

Tags: perl

So I'm trying use [`Rose::HTML::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Rose%3a%3aHTML%3a%3aForm) and I want my fields to appear based on 'rank' rather than by name (the default) .

I've written a comparator subroutine:

```
sub _order_by_rank {
  my ($self, $one, $two) = @_;
  return $one->rank <=> $two->rank;
};
```

and referenced it in my form constructor:

```
Rose::HTML::Form->new(method => 'post', compare_fields => \&_order_by_rank);
```

But I am then left with:

```
Can't call method "name" on unblessed reference at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Rose/HTML/Form/Field/Collection.pm line 405.
```

It seems to call the comparator before I've added anything.

After constructing the form object, I add some fields and then call init_fields:

```
$form->add_fields(
    id => { type => 'hidden', value => "", rank => 0 },
    number => { type => 'int', size => 4, required => 1, label => 'Plant Number', rank => 1 },
    name => { type => 'text', size => 25, required => 1, label => 'Plant Name', rank => 2 },
    ...
  );
$form->init_fields;
```

According to the documentation this is something people usually do. What it doesn't explain is *how* to do it.

Hopefully someone can explain this to me before I have to buy a new keyboard :)

Comment: Is this your actual code? `\_order_by_rank` should be `\&_order_by_rank`.

Comment: Yeah it is. Also, quite right - Seems I must have pressed something when copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation it looks as though, rather than passing in a subroutine reference, you need to subclass `Rose::HTML::Form` and override the `compare_fields` method.

The default comparison method is `Rose::HTML::Form::compare_fields`. You have to create subclasses if you want different sorting methods for different forms.

It would help me to explain further if you showed your full code.

Comment: @PaulRohrlach: You're welcome. Clearly you know how to write subclasses and override inherited methods. I was getting ready to explain that part as well!